# JAX-metal error: 'anec.reshape' op failed: input tensor dimensions are not supported on ANEs

Tags: python, tensorflow, metal, jax

I just tested [`jax-metal`](https://developer.apple.com/metal/jax/) on my M1 Max MacBook Pro. However, I already get a warning when loading the MNIST dataset as follows.

```py
import gzip
import os
import struct
import urllib.request
import jax.numpy as jnp


def mnist():
    url_dir = "https://storage.googleapis.com/cvdf-datasets/mnist"
    target_dir = os.getcwd() + "/data/mnist"

    # download images and labels into data folder
    url = f"{url_dir}/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz"
    target = f"{target_dir}/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz"
    if not os.path.exists(target):
        os.makedirs(target_dir, exist_ok=True)
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, target)
        print(f"Downloaded {url} to {target}")

    # load images into memory
    target = f"{target_dir}/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz"
    with gzip.open(target, "rb") as fh:
        _, batch, rows, cols = struct.unpack(">IIII", fh.read(16))
        shape = (batch, 1, rows, cols)
        images = jnp.frombuffer(fh.read(), dtype=jnp.uint8).reshape(shape)

    return images


if __name__ == "__main__":
    images = mnist()
    print(images.shape)
```

The warning states:

> loc("jit(reshape)/jit(main)/reshape[new_sizes=(60000, 1, 28, 28)
> dimensions=None]"("train_stack.py":25:0)): error: 'anec.reshape' op
> failed: input tensor dimensions are not supported on ANEs.

Here, (60000, 1, 28, 28) is the shape of the images in the MNIST dataset. Still, the program finishes running successfully. Now, I am wondering about the following.

- What are the consequences of `anec.reshape` not being supported?
- Can I avoid this warning (by side-stepping the `reshape` in some way) or do we just need to wait until `anec.reshape` is fully supported?

**Extra information.**

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| GPU | Apple M1 Max |
| Operating System | MacOS Sonoma v14.1 |
| `jax-metal` | 0.0.4 |

Comment: `jax-metal` is currently experimental with very limited support of JAX operations. See the list of open issues here: [google/jax/issues:Apple GPU (metal) plugin](https://github.com/google/jax/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Aissue+label%3A%22Apple+GPU+%28Metal%29+plugin%22)